# Wordpress shortcode linked to another DB

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, shortcode

First thing first, this is my first shortcode attempt.
It is worthed mention that I'm also using woocommerce on my website.

**Let's start:**

I know that to add shortcodes into wordpress, you need to write something similar to the code below into the functions.php file: (this is just an example)

```
function myshortcode() {   
    return "This is a shortcode example!";
}
add_shortcode( 'mycode', 'myshortcode' );
```

and if i add `[mycode]` into the wordpress page editor, the preview shows my text correctly.

But what if i need to use a variable (in my case **woocommerce order number**) in the shortcode?

Let's say i need to compare **woocommerce_order_number** with **my_custom_uid** (inserted into another database, **outside** wordpress).

I usually use a db request like the one below, and usually it works fine (as before, this is only an example):

```
select 'my_custom_uid' from 'my_custom_database' where 'woocommerce_order_number' = '1234'
```

The problem is that i don't know the woocommerce_order_number (it changes everytime!), because this shortcode needs to go inside an html email body i need to send out to customers after they placed the order.

How can i get the customer woocommerce order (variable that changes everytime) so that i will be able to use it into my shortcode to link it to my custom_uid?

If the question is not clear enough, please feel free to ask for clarification!
thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to solve this, and here's what i did if someone is interested:

```
<?PHP

add_action('fue_before_variable_replacements', 'register_variable_replacements', 11, 4);
add_action('fue_email_variables_list', 'email_variables_list');

/**
 * This gets called to replace the variable in the email with an actual value
 * @param $var - Modify this: array key is the variable name, value is the replacement
 */


function register_variable_replacements($var,  $email_data, $queue_item, $email){
    global $wpdb;
    // Look up UID from order number
    $orderNumber = $var->get_variables()['order_number'];
    $sql = " //Your sql statement here...//";
    $results = $wpdb->get_results($sql);
    $UID = $results[0]->meta_value;
    $variables = array(
        'uid' => $UID
    );
    $var->register($variables);
}

function email_variables_list($email)
{
    global $woocommerce;
    ?>
    <li class="var hideable var_subscriptions">
        <strong>{uid}</strong>
        <img class="help_tip" title="<?php _e('Order UID', 'follow_up_emails'); ?>" src="<?php echo $woocommerce->plugin_url(); ?>/assets/images/help.png" width="16" height="16"/>
    </li>
    <?php
}
```

Now on your follow up email plugin, you can use `{uid}` as a variable and this will be replaced with the correct value on every email.

I though the best way was to use short code, but then i discovered this filter and i think this is the best way to handle this. This code is also pretty flexible and you can add as many variables as you want.

Hope this can help someone.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a reason to use a shortcode. If you want to add something to an email, you should use one of the hooks in the email. For example:

```
function kia_display_email_order_meta( $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text ) {
    $some_field = get_post_meta( $order->id, '_some_field', true ),
    $another_field = get_post_meta( $order->id, '_another_field', true ),
    if( $plain_text ){
        echo 'The value for some field is ' . $some_field . ' while the value of another field is ' . $another_field;
    } else {
        echo '<p>The value for <strong>some field</strong> is ' . $some_field. ' while the value of <strong>another field</strong> is ' . $another_field . '</p>';
    }
}
add_action('woocommerce_email_customer_details', 'kia_display_email_order_meta', 30, 3 );
```

Note that the `$order` object is the first parameter available to the `kia_display_email_order_meta` function. So you'd be able to get the ID via `$order->id`. This should add the data after the customer address details, but there are other hooks available if `woocommerce_email_customer_details` isn't appropriate.

Comment: The reason why i wanted to use a shortcode is because i'm using a plugin called woocommerce followup emails that allows you to sent emails after some time. I can only use shortcode to put into the email templates apparently

Comment: If the emails follow the pattern of WooCommerce emails then they should still have hooks that you can use.